# How to fill second column in emacs Two-Column mode with newlines to length of first column?

Tags: automation, emacs, newline

I am using emacs in Two-Column mode to "edge code" some notes, basically adding keywords per line. I open the text file with the notes in it; I tab to column 72 and insert a '|'; I set the mark to its right and 'C-x 6 s' to split into two columns. Then 'C-x o' to get to the 2C buffer.

But this new 2C buffer is only one line long, which prevents me from scrolling beyond where I have entered text and newlines to make it longer.

How could I quickly, even perhaps automatically, fill this 2C buffer with one newline for each line in the first column (original text file) buffer, so that I can scroll both buffers a screen at a time?

Comment: I suggest that you define a keyboard macro for it.

Comment: That makes sense, but the length of the first buffer is different every time. I guess I am going to make a function to do the move-to-column, insert |, 2C-split and other-window, but I am unclear on how to get the line length of the original buffer (the one I split).

Comment: Apparently not beyond my newb-ness. After 2C-split the active window is the original buffer with the text in it so I used `(setq first-buffer-lines (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))`

Answer (score 1):

These are the functions I ended up making. For some reason calling 2C-split from within a function causes an error so I made a keyboard macro to run 2C-set-separator, 2C-split and then 2C-insert-newlines.

```
(defun 2C-set-separator ()
       "Insert a separator at column 72."
       (interactive)
       (move-to-column '72 t)
       (insert "|")
)

(defun 2C-insert-newlines ()
  "Inserts newlines in the 2C buffer."
  (interactive)
  (setq first-buffer-lines (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))
  (other-window 1)
  (while (< (line-number-at-pos) first-buffer-lines)
   (insert "\n")
   (forward-line))
 (beginning-of-buffer)
)
```